# Which version of Java for Applet recommended?

Tags: java, java-7, japplet, java.nio.file

Are people still writing Java Applets with Java 1.6 or have most Developers moved on to 1.7? Our applet was written in 1.7 using the java.nio.file and WatchEvent, but many of our customers still have not upgraded to 1.7 yet on PCs or Mac. As of writing, is developing an applet in Java 1.7 a bigger security risk than using 1.6?

Comment: *"Are people still writing Java Applets with.."*  Most people avoid applets completely.

Comment: Oops.  Forgot to mention *"As of writing, is developing an applet in Java 1.7 a bigger security risk than using 1.6?"* I am not in a position to comment on that, but generally.  Let the user choose the JRE they are most confident with.  If you compile the code for 1.6, they can still use 1.7 to run it, albeit without the 1.7 functionality you desire to implement.  'The customer is always right' when it comes to choice of software plug-in version.

Comment: As a follow-up question, what are most people using to browse PC and Mac file systems? We used the Java Applet to allow file browsing on both file systems. I'm guessing for Google Drive's case is using Html5 on Chrome and FF, while making users download an ActiveX component in IE and not supporting Safari. Unfortunately, many of our users are still using IE8+.

Comment: *"As a follow-up question, what are most people using to browse PC and Mac file systems?"*  Don't really know, sorry.